# A Blood Relation problem

Tags: logical-deduction, family

> In a family there are two married couples, two daughters, three sons and two brothers. Rohan is the son of Soni who is the daughter of Rajeev and wife of Lucky. Riya is the grand daughter of Rajeev. Pyare is the son of Toni and husband of Reema who is the grand daughter in law of Sanjeev. Sanjeev and Rajeev are real brothers.

Now the follow up questions are:

1. How is Lucky related to Reema? (Unable to figure out completeley. It would be great if someone helps me to figure out how to use in-laws in the analogy when he or she is related to brother of father in law).
2. How is Pyare related to Sanjeev? (I calculated it to be grandson from the tree).

Is this tree I constructed correct?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a few mistakes in your diagram, possibly because you are misunderstanding the complicated English sentences.

In particular, Lucky is married to Soni (and not Rajeev) because it says "Soni who is the daughter of Rajeev and wife of Lucky", which means that "Soni is the daughter of Rajeev" and "Soni is the wife of Lucky".

Also Reema is married to Pyare (and not Toni), because it says "Pyare is the son of Toni and husband of Reema", which means "Pyare is the son of Toni" and "Pyare is the husband of Reema".

The family tree is then:

> ```
>      _______________ | _________________
>     |                                   |
>  Sanjeev(m)                          Rajeev(m)
>     |                                   |
>     |                                   |
>   Toni(m)                  Lucky(m) x Somi(f)
>     |                          ____ | ____
>     |                         |           |
>  Pyare(m) x Reema(f)        Rohan(m)    Riya(f)
> ```

There are indeed two married couples (Pyare/Reema, Lucky/Somi), two daughters (Somi, Riya), three sons (Toni, Pyare, Rohan) and two brothers (Sanjeev, Rajeev).

> How is Lucky related to Reema?

This is tricky, but I think it is called

> Lucky is Reema's first cousin-in-law once removed. Lucky is one generation up, related via her husband's great-grandparents.

> How is Pyare related to Sanjeev?

> He is indeed Sanjeev's grandson.

Comment: What is meant by first cousin in law? Can you explain this?

Comment: @RajorshiKoyal See [cousin on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cousin) to understand "First cousin once removed". Lucky is Pyare's first cousin once removed. Lucky is not related by blood to Reema, but only via Reema's marriage to Pyare, so I added "in-law" to make that clear.

Comment: How is Rajeev related to Toni?

Comment: @RajorshiKoyal Rajeev is Toni's uncle. Toni is Rajeev's nephew.

Comment: To reach upto Lucky from Reema we need to use in law twice I feel. That seems very weird for me.

Comment: Please justify.

Comment: @RajorshiKoyal 'in-law' is never used more than once. It purely means that someone is not a blood relative. For example, my wife's parents are my parents-in-law; my brother's wife is my sister-in-law. We use 'x removed' (where 'x' is 'once', 'twice', 'three times' etc. as appropriate) to show differences between generations - 'in-law' has nothing to do with this. Jaap is correct here. [EDIT: In practice, if Jaap's family tree is correct, Lucky and Reema are barely related at all, as they have both married in to different generations of different branches of the same family...]

Comment: @Stiv That is ok but how could Lucky be cousin-in law to Reema?

Comment: Can you secribe what relation Rajeev has to reema?

Comment: @RajorshiKoyal *She isn't*. Lucky is cousin-in-law **once removed** to Reema. Lucky is cousin-in-law to *Toni*, because Toni is cousins with Lucky's spouse. Go **one** generation further down the tree to Reema and you have Lucky being cousin-in-law **once removed** to Reema.

Comment: @RajorshiKoyal Working off Jaap's diagram again, Rajeev is Reema's **great uncle-in-law**, because Rajeev is Pyare's great uncle and Reema is married to Pyare, hence the relation between Rajeev and Reema is only 'in law' because they are related only by marriage, not by blood.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123346/discussion-between-rajorshi-koyal-and-stiv).

Comment: @RajorshiKoyal Yes, that is a good point - I had overlooked that Lucky married into the family. For some relations "in-law" is never used. For example, aunts and uncles can be a parent's sibling or married to a parent's sibling. But this is not so for cousin. So Lucky is Pyare's first cousin-in-law once removed. Reema could say "Lucky is my husband's first cousin-in-law once removed." but there does not seem to be a way to formulate it more directly. "In-law" would not normally be used twice, except as a joke.

Comment: Somi is Rajeev's daughter.Somi is related to Pyare by blood.Then how is Lucky related?